# I have a NullPointerException using the SurfaceView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have this code. It isn't complex at all, I'm learning and I was practising and messing around with the surface view. I only want 2 rectangles to be there and an image going down. When we touch in the second rectangle, the image starts going up. We touch the one in the left and the image restarts going down. When it arrives the line 89, it stops and gives the null pointer exception. I guess the error happens when I create the canvas.

```
public class LearningThreads extends Activity {

ActivitySurface activitySurface;
boolean crossGoesUp = false;//Sets if the cross goes up or down
int leftRectangle1, topRectangle1, rightRectangle1, bottomRectangle1;
int leftRectangle2, topRectangle2, rightRectangle2, bottomRectangle2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    activitySurface = new ActivitySurface(this);
    activitySurface.setOnTouchListener(new canvasClicked());
    setContentView(activitySurface);//Sets the content to be the class we've created
}

protected void onPause() {//When the app is paused, it calls the method which pauses the thread that is constantly running
    super.onPause();
    activitySurface.pause();
}

protected void onResume() {//When the app starts or restarts, it calls the method which starts the thread
    super.onResume();
    activitySurface.resume();
}

public class canvasClicked implements OnTouchListener {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {//Only if the user starts touching something because I'm not interested in when he releases
            if (e.getX() <= leftRectangle1 && e.getX() >= rightRectangle1 && e.getY() <= topRectangle1 && e.getY() >= bottomRectangle1) {//Tests if the user touched one of the rectangles
                crossGoesUp = false;
            }
            if (e.getX() <= leftRectangle2 && e.getX() >= rightRectangle2 && e.getY() <= topRectangle2 && e.getY() >= bottomRectangle2) {//Tests if the user touched the other rectangle
                crossGoesUp = true;
            }
        }
        return false;//It doesn't repeat
    }
}

public class ActivitySurface extends SurfaceView {

    Thread mainThread;
    boolean isRunning = false;//Sets when the app is running or not
    SurfaceHolder holder;//Gives us useful methods to use in the canvas
    int crossY = 0;//Sets the y coordinate of the cross

    public ActivitySurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
    }

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
        mainThread = new Thread(new mainThread());
        mainThread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            mainThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class mainThread implements Runnable {//Takes care of the thread
        public void run() {
            while(isRunning) {
                if (holder.getSurface().isValid())//Tests if the surface is valid, if it is not it won't do anything until it is
                    continue;

                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();//Creating the canvas: it has a mistake, everytime I use the canvas it gives a NullPointerException
                canvas.drawRGB(50, 50, 50);//Setting the color of the canvas

                leftRectangle1 = canvas.getWidth()/4 - 40;//Setting the variables so they can be used outside this Thread
                topRectangle1 = canvas.getHeight()/2 - 25;
                rightRectangle1 = canvas.getWidth()/4 + 40;
                bottomRectangle1 = canvas.getHeight()/2 + 25;

                leftRectangle2 = canvas.getWidth()/4 + (canvas.getWidth()/4) * 2 - 40;
                topRectangle2 = canvas.getHeight()/2 - 25;
                rightRectangle2 = canvas.getWidth()/4 + (canvas.getWidth()/4) * 2 + 40;
                bottomRectangle2 = canvas.getHeight()/2 + 25;

                Paint paint = new Paint();//Setting the paint which will define the colors of the rectangles
                paint.setARGB(0, 100, 100, 100);

                Rect rectangle1 = new Rect();//Setting the position of the rectangle 1
                rectangle1.set(leftRectangle1, topRectangle1, rightRectangle1, bottomRectangle1);

                Rect rectangle2 = new Rect();//Setting the position of the rectangle 2
                rectangle2.set(leftRectangle2, topRectangle2, rightRectangle2, bottomRectangle2);

                canvas.drawRect(rectangle1, paint);//Drawing the rectangles
                canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, paint);

                Bitmap cross = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.animation);//Creating the image which is going to go up and down
                canvas.drawBitmap(cross, canvas.getWidth()/2 - cross.getWidth()/2, crossY, paint);

                if (crossGoesUp) {//If the crossGoesUp is true, that means the user last touch was in the rectangle 2, so the image goes up
                    if (crossY < -cross.getHeight())//Tests if the image isn't out of bounds
                        crossY = canvas.getHeight() + cross.getHeight();
                    crossY -= 5;
                } else {
                    if (crossY > canvas.getHeight() + cross.getHeight())//Same as above
                        crossY = -cross.getHeight();
                    crossY += 5;
                }

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
05-02 07:13:41.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-103

05-02 07:13:41.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): Process: garden.apps.my_apps, PID: 1634

05-02 07:13:41.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-02 07:13:41.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): at com.apps.my_apps.LearningThreads$ActivitySurface$mainThread.run(LearningThreads.java:90)

05-02 07:13:41.897: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace if you are having issues with your code

Comment: @BojanKseneman true, please post your log cat

Comment: and add comment to line no 86.

Comment: @user3676184 you mean 89?

Comment: @Bojan Kseneman:  yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use SurfaceHolder.Callback, your paint is invisible 
paint.setARGB(alpha,Red,Green,Blue) - alpha 0..255 0-invisible 255-visible

```
public class LearningThreads extends Activity  {

ActivitySurface activitySurface;
boolean crossGoesUp = false;//Sets if the cross goes up or down
int leftRectangle1, topRectangle1, rightRectangle1, bottomRectangle1;
int leftRectangle2, topRectangle2, rightRectangle2, bottomRectangle2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    activitySurface = new ActivitySurface(this);
    activitySurface.setOnTouchListener(new canvasClicked());
    setContentView(activitySurface);//Sets the content to be the class we've created
}

protected void onPause() {//When the app is paused, it calls the method which pauses the thread that is constantly running
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {//When the app starts or restarts, it calls the method which starts the thread
    super.onResume();
}

public class canvasClicked implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {//Only if the user starts touching something because I'm not interested in when he releases
            if (e.getX() <= leftRectangle1 && e.getX() >= rightRectangle1 && e.getY() <= topRectangle1 && e.getY() >= bottomRectangle1) {//Tests if the user touched one of the rectangles
                crossGoesUp = false;
            }
            if (e.getX() <= leftRectangle2 && e.getX() >= rightRectangle2 && e.getY() <= topRectangle2 && e.getY() >= bottomRectangle2) {//Tests if the user touched the other rectangle
                crossGoesUp = true;
            }
        }
        return false;//It doesn't repeat
    }
}

public class ActivitySurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Thread mainThread;
    boolean isRunning = false;//Sets when the app is running or not
    SurfaceHolder holder;//Gives us useful methods to use in the canvas
    int crossY = 0;//Sets the y coordinate of the cross

    public ActivitySurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
        mainThread = new Thread(new mainThread());
        mainThread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        try {
            mainThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class mainThread implements Runnable {//Takes care of the thread

        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())//Tests if the surface is valid, if it is not it won't do anything until it is
                    continue;

                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();//Creating the canvas: it has a mistake, everytime I use the canvas it gives a NullPointerException
                canvas.drawRGB(50, 50, 50);//Setting the color of the canvas

                leftRectangle1 = canvas.getWidth() / 4 - 40;//Setting the variables so they can be used outside this Thread
                topRectangle1 = canvas.getHeight() / 2 - 25;
                rightRectangle1 = canvas.getWidth() / 4 + 40;
                bottomRectangle1 = canvas.getHeight() / 2 + 25;

                leftRectangle2 = canvas.getWidth() / 4 + (canvas.getWidth() / 4) * 2 - 40;
                topRectangle2 = canvas.getHeight() / 2 - 25;
                rightRectangle2 = canvas.getWidth() / 4 + (canvas.getWidth() / 4) * 2 + 40;
                bottomRectangle2 = canvas.getHeight() / 2 + 25;

                Paint paint = new Paint();//Setting the paint which will define the colors of the rectangles
                paint.setARGB(255, 100, 100, 100);

                Rect rectangle1 = new Rect();//Setting the position of the rectangle 1
                rectangle1.set(leftRectangle1, topRectangle1, rightRectangle1, bottomRectangle1);

                Rect rectangle2 = new Rect();//Setting the position of the rectangle 2
                rectangle2.set(leftRectangle2, topRectangle2, rightRectangle2, bottomRectangle2);

                canvas.drawRect(rectangle1, paint);//Drawing the rectangles
                canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, paint);

                Bitmap cross = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.animation);//Creating the image which is going to go up and down
                canvas.drawBitmap(cross, canvas.getWidth() / 2 - cross.getWidth() / 2, crossY, paint);

                if (crossGoesUp) {//If the crossGoesUp is true, that means the user last touch was in the rectangle 2, so the image goes up
                    if (crossY < -cross.getHeight())//Tests if the image isn't out of bounds
                        crossY = canvas.getHeight() + cross.getHeight();
                    crossY -= 5;
                } else {
                    if (crossY > canvas.getHeight() + cross.getHeight())//Same as above
                        crossY = -cross.getHeight();
                    crossY += 5;
                }

                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        pause();
    }

}
```

Comment: You've only added the callback and changed the alpha value of the paint, right? If so, it didn't work, it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: I test i does work, i also move the resume,pause and change more stuff... copy it over yours and test it

Comment: the resume,pause should not be called from the activity only from the surfaceCreate, sufaceDestroyed

Comment: Yeah, it works, sorry. I forgot to put the exclamation mark as I said. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i also changed isValid() to !isValid() because continue means run back to the start of the loop.

Comment: That was the main problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
someActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Your code to run in GUI thread here
    }//public void run() {
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figger it out by myself, the problem was in this block of code:

```
if (holder.getSurface().isValid())//Tests if the surface is valid, if it is not it won't do anything until it 
    continue;
```

I forgot to put the exclamation mark, so the app only did what was below when the surface was not valid and it gave me a NullPointerException.
Thank you anyway.